# Call method of a ViewModel from MainViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, viewmodel, communication

I'm currentyl having a problem by communicating between 2 ViewModels.
Download my app here to see the problem: http://www76.zippyshare.com/v/26081324/file.html

I have 2 views.

- A 'MainView.xaml' with the datacontext 'MainViewModel'.
- A 'FirstView.xaml' with the datacontext 'FirstViewModel'.

The MainView has a ContentControl with the Content = FirstView. My FirstViewModel looked something like this:

```
public class FirstViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public FirstViewModel()
        {
        One = "0";
        Two = "0";
        Ergebnis = 0;
    }
    private string _one;
    public string One
    {
        get { return _one; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                    _one = value;
                    Calculate();
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => One);
            }
        }
    }

    private string _two;
    public string Two
    {
        get { return _two; }
        set
        {
                    _two = value;
                    Calculate();
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Two9;
        }

    }

    private decimal _ergebnis;
    public decimal Ergebnis
    {
        get { return _ergebnis; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (value != _ergebnis)
                {
                    _ergebnis = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Ergebnis);
                }
            }


        }
    }

    public void Calculate()
    {
        if (Two != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                Ergebnis = i;
            }
            Ergebnis = (decimal.Parse(One) + decimal.Parse(Two));
        }
    }
```

As you can see, every time the value of the property 'One' or 'Two' is being changed, it'll call Calculate(). What I want now is that when I click on a button in the MainView, the MainViewModel has to call Calculate() in FirstViewModel. So I commented out the Calculate() in the propertys and implemented a RelayCommand in my MainViewModel:

Button in MainView

```
<Button Grid.Row="3" Command="{Binding ChangeValue}" />
```

MainViewModel

```
public MainViewModel
{
    ChangeValue = new RelayCommand(ChangeValueCommandExecute);
}

public RelayCommand ChangeValue { get; private set; }
private FirstViewModel fwm;

private void ChangeValueCommandExecute()
{
    //CurrentView = Content of the ContentControl in the MainView, which is FirstView
    if (CurrentView.Content.ToString().Contains("FirstView"))
    {   
        fwm.Calculate();
    }
}
```

This means when I click on the Button, ChangeValueCommandExecute() is being called. The Command will call fwm.Calculate() and set the new sum (=Ergebnis). The problem is that when Calculate() is being called, the value of 'One' and 'Two' is always "0". So how do I call a method of a ViewModel in another ViewModel?

Edit: To make it clear: I want to call the method 'Calculate()' of FirstViewModel() without using 'new FirstViewModel()'!

Comment: I might be missing something, but I don't see how the Calculate method should change the values of "One" and "Two". Only the "Ergebnis" value is changed.

Comment: Right, didn't mention it in my first post.. The FirstView.xaml has 2 Textbox. Each of them Binds to the property, like <TextBox Text="{Binding One, Mode=TwoWay}"/> and 'Ergebnis' -> <TextBlock Content="{Binding Ergebnis}"/> . You can download the program to see it by yourself. Like I said, Calculation works fine when I uncomment 'Calculate()' in the setter property, but I want to call Calculate() only when I click on a button in another view (with DataContext to anther ViewModel).

Comment: Have you debugged this? Have you looked at what is happening in Calculate() when the button is clicked? Typically if I need to communicate between view models in an MVVM app I will use a messaging system that all view models can use to pass messages.

Comment: Yes, I debugged it. The value of 'One' and 'Two' is "0" (standard value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't view your project because it requires Windows 8 but are you sure the `FirstViewModel` you have as the `DataContext` of your `FirstView` is the same `FirstViewModel` you're referring to in your `MainViewModel`? From what I can see, you're newing up a `FirstViewModel` in the constructor of the `MainViewModel` which is private.

Comment: yes, that's right... I'm newing up a FirstViewModel in my constructor of the MainViewModel. Since I don't know how else to call the method 'Calculate()' in the FirstViewModel, I'm doing it like this... Any other way to call the method 'Calculate89' without creating a new instance of FirstViewModelß

Comment: Yeah, you should have a public reference to your FirstViewModel in the MainViewModel. Then your main window's DataContext will be the MainViewModel and the ContentControl's DataContext will be the reference to the same instance of FirstViewModel that you have in your MainViewModel.

Comment: K, got it! It's working now. Like you said, I just have to create a variable in the constructor of MainViewModel for FirstViewModel (i.E. fvm = new FirstViewModel). Then say MyContent.DataContext = fvm; Now I can call fvm.Calculate(); and the values won't be 0.